# Get Columns of a Table by GetSchema() method

Tags: c#, ado.net, schema

I want to get list of columns of a table using `GetSchema` method in `ADO.Net`, my code is:

```
var dtCols = con.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { "DBName", "TableName" });
```

And i get an empty `DataTable`, what is the problem?

Comment: stab in the dark, but try `var dtCols = con.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { "DBName", null, "TableName" });`

Comment: Thanks Matthew that's worked, Please write your solution as a Answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You must specify a parameter for the "owner" restriction.

```
var dtCols = con.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { "DBName", null, "TableName" });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my complete solution.

You just need to provide `tableName` and `connectionString` to this method:

```
// I took HUGE help from this Microsoft website: - AshishK
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_GetSchema_System_String_System_String___
public static List<string> GetAllColumnNamesOfATable(string tableName, string connectionString)
{
    var allColumnNames = new List<string>();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Connect to the database then retrieve the schema information.  
        connection.Open();

        // You can specify the Catalog, Schema, Table Name, Column Name to get the specified column(s).
        // You can use four restrictions for Column, so you should create a 4 members array.
        String[] columnRestrictions = new String[4];

        // For the array, 0-member represents Catalog; 1-member represents Schema;
        // 2-member represents Table Name; 3-member represents Column Name.
        // Now we specify the Table_Name and Column_Name of the columns what we want to get schema information.
        columnRestrictions[2] = tableName;

        DataTable allColumnsSchemaTable = connection.GetSchema("Columns", columnRestrictions);

        foreach (DataRow row in allColumnsSchemaTable.Rows)
        {
            var columnName = row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME");
                
            //You can capture other fields as well, like so:
            //var dataType = row.Field<string>("DATA_TYPE");
            //var characterMaxLength = row.Field<int?>("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH");

            allColumnNames.Add(columnName);
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    return allColumnNames;
}
```

---

PS: If you'd like to capture other information about the columns this way, the following fields are also available:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could both of these answers be generalized a bit with:

`dtCols = con.GetSchema("Columns", new[] {con.DataSource, null, "TableName"});`

This is assuming that "TableName" is the name of the table that you want the schema for.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for clarification?  Answers are reserved for answering the question, not for commenting or seeking help.

Comment: If your connection is already connected to the database, you can also just specifiy a null for the database name instead of con.DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the following worked..

```
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlText, con)) {
    var sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    var a = sqlReader.GetColumnSchema();                        
}
```