# Retrieving the Columns of the table with GetSchema

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I would like to retrieve a list of the columns for all the tables in the list matchingTableList:

```
foreach (var table in matchingTableList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Analyzing " + table);
    var sourceTableRows = sqlSourceConnection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] {SourceDatabase, null, table, null});
    var destTableRows = sqlDestConnection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { DestDatabase, null, table, null });
    Console.WriteLine("Number of fields " + sourceTableRows.Rows.Count);
    //iterate through every field in the table
    foreach (var row in sourceTableRows.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Analyzing col " + row);
        //if the field is not present, add it to the list containing the added fields for the current table
        if (destTableRows.Columns.Contains((row.ToString()))) continue;
        if (!changedTablesAddedFields[table].Contains(row.ToString()))
        {
            changedTablesAddedFields[table].Add(row.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The count of the sourceTableRows.Rows is always 0, even if the tables have columns in the database.
What am I missing?

EDIT1: I can retrieve the values when I do

```
var sourceTableRows = sqlSourceConnection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] {null, null, table, null});
var destTableRows = sqlDestConnection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { null, null, table, null });
```

But why does it work like that?

EDIT2: I found out that this is the syntax for MSSQL:

```
var sourceTableRows = sqlSourceConnection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] {SourceDatabase, null, table, null});
var destTableRows = sqlDestConnection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { DestDatabase, null, table, null });
```

While MySQL requires this:

```
var sourceTableRows = sqlSourceConnection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { null, SourceDatabase, table, null});
var destTableRows = sqlDestConnection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { null, DestDatabase, table, null });
```

Still, when I try to get the name of the column with

```
var rowName = (string) row[2];
```

The only thing I get is the name of the table. I debugged the application and I cannot find the columns name in the row variable. What am I missing?

Comment: What is DestDatabase here?

Comment: Destination database, a string containing the database name.

Comment: Sorry SourceDatabase. If you mispell that you don't get the list.

Comment: It's not mispelled. It's the same value I use when I create the sql connections.

Comment: Well, tried this code (at least with just the source part) and it works as expected with or without the database (Catalog) name. So perhaps there is something different at work here. I think you need to start the debugger and check the values passed.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71339440/8644294

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet (used for SqlCE but applicable to other versions of SQL Server: just use the corresponding SQL objects). Also, pay attention to the comments as they pretty much explain the code operational logic:

```
        // `ConnectionString` specifies the Database
        SqlCeConnection connectionSql = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
        connectionSql.Open();

        // create new `DataAdapter` on `connectionSql` and Your `SelectQuery` text
        SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapterSql = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
        dataAdapterSql.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(SelectQuery, connectionSql);

        // create DataSet
        DataSet dataSet= new DataSet();

        // retrieve TableSchema
        DataTable[] _dataTablesSchema = dataAdapterSql.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Source);

        // there is only one Table in DataSet, so use 0-index
        DataTable  sourceDataTable = _dataTablesSchema[0];

        // use DataAdapter to Fill Dataset
        dataAdapterSql.Fill(sourceDataTable );
```

You can also use a short-cut to shorten the code:

```
    // there is only one Table in DataSet, so use 0-index
    DataTable sourceDataTable= = dataAdapterSql.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Source)[0];
```

Hope this will help. Rgds,

PS. In your own code, as a debugging recommendation: put a break line and make sure that `sourceDataTable !=null`

Comment: I'm using MySQL, so the code is not really suitable for my case.